How to perform MAX date in data entity
I am attempting to create a data entity with the SysUserLog table to export the latest login date for a user (createdDateTime field). I am unsure how to perform the MAX date with a data entity to represent the following SQL query:
select UserId, Max(createdDateTime) AS 'LastLogin'
from SYSUSERLOG
group by UserId

Here is how I made the structure of the entity:

Is there a range I can apply for the MAX(createdDateTime) or should I go via a SysComputedColumn?
Thanks

I wouldn't use the grouping, instead consider:

adding a Range to filter by UserId to ensure the returned records are for a specific user,
adding createdDateTime field to the OrderBy section on the query (Direction property: Descending),
setting First Only to Yes on the SysUserLog data source withing your query.

This way, you will only return one result with the highest createdDateTime for a specific user.
